# "It" -- a dummy subject or not?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, dummy-pronouns

The following are two example sentences of "versus" in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

The first question: Is the "it" a dummy subject in both?

The second question: Could the "it" be replaced by "the match" in the first sentence and "the dilemma" in the second?

> It is France versus Brazil in the final.

> It was the promise of better job opportunities versus the inconvenience of moving away and leaving her friends.

Comment: Is "the match" supposed to be in the first sentence and "the dilemma" in the second? I don't see those phrases.

Comment: I was asking if "the match" and "the dilemma' could be used instead of "it' in those sentences.

Comment: Oh. Please edit your question then to make that clear. "Refers to" doesn't necessarily mean "can be replaced by".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan     Question(s) updated

Comment: I don't think you can really say without more context.  For example, if the second sentence were preceded by "What was on her mind?" then the *it* is definitely not a dummy, because it refers to "The thing that was on her mind."

Answer (score 1):

Neither "it" seems to refer to any specific thing that the reader would be expected to know of, so yes, I'd consider both to be dummy pronouns. (In [Wikipedia's language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun), I'd say it doesn't "provide a contextually explicit meaning of its referent", and in [Wiktionary's language](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dummy_pronoun), I'd say it doesn't have "a specific referent".)

Note that the second sentence seems incomplete without some context; something like this would be more common:

> It was the promise of better job opportunities versus the inconvenience of moving away and leaving her friends that convinced her to stay with the company.

In this case, the that-clause has been "extraposed" from the subject position (which is now occupied by the dummy pronoun "it").

---

In casual speech, one might say "the match" and "the dilemma" in each of those sentences. However, I think that that would be imprecise. (For example, the first sentence would say "the match is France", but a match is not a team.) I might instead say:

> The match pitted France versus Brazil in the final.

> The dilemma concerned the promise of better job opportunities versus the inconvenience of moving away and leaving her friends.

Comment: Is the following okay?

A: Why does Mary look so troubled?
B: It is the promise of better job opportunities versus the inconvenience of moving away and leaving her friends.

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, the context from the first sentence makes the second sentence sound much better.